# Embedded types and polymorphism with structs

Tags: struct, go, polymorphism

I'm creating an API, and I have two different structs for JSON responses; one for single records and one for collection of records:

```
type Model struct {
  Id uint
}

type Collection struct {
  Records []Model
}
```

A `Model` is just a struct representation of database data (for say, a User), and a `Collection` is a collection of models.

The issue is that there will be separate structs that embed the `Model` type, like so:

```
type User struct {
    *Model
    Name string
}
```

And since a `User` doesn't satisfy the `Model` type, I can't append it to the `Collection` struct like this:

```
user := User{&Model{1}, "Jon"}
uc := &Collection{[]User{user}}
```

How can I make the Records struct accept struct types that implement `Model`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

- Make another collection type
- Use interfaces instead

Implementing separate collections like `UserCollection`, `BarCollection`, `FooCollection` is an option if you do not have too many foos and bars.

The other way is to use either the generic empty interface type `interface{}` which will hold values of any type (since every instance of every type satisfies the empty interface):

```
type Collection struct {
    Records []interface{}
}
```

This has a number of drawbacks such as that you have to do a type assertion every time you access the `Records` field, that you can put everything in there by mistake and that you have to use reflection to do most manipulations.

The better way to use interfaces would be to implement a model interface and let every type that is a model implement the interface:

```
type Model interface {
    ImplementsModel()
}

type BaseModel struct {
    Id uint
}

func (b *BaseModel) ImplementsModel() {}

type User struct {
    *BaseModel
    Name string
}

type Collection struct {
    Records []Model
}
```

Of course you can remove the `ImplementsModel` dummy method once you have meaningful methods. This dummy method is just there to distinguish the interface from the empty interface so that you cannot put integer values or strings in place of actual models into the collection.

Comment: But in your example, while I can store BaseModel into Records, how can I get back those BaseModels again? If I get collection[0] that would be a Model, not a BaseModel, so how could I access the Id field?

Comment: You check the record type by using type assertion and then access the field. For example, `m := Records[0].(*User); println(m.Id);`.

Comment: The thing is that you need to know the exact type inserted in the `Records` array. If you do type assertion with `BaseModel`, but what is stored is actually an `User`, the assertion fails. `User` is-not-a `BaseModel`. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/cnLnVpKTNk

Comment: Yes. If you want that all records have an identifier, you would implement it using the `Model` interface, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Model struct is not a type User struct.
User can't behave Model even if embedded it.

This case, you can use interface like below.
http://play.golang.org/p/Hh0zIT9yFC

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    type Model interface {
        GetID() uint
    }

    type BaseModel struct {
        Id uint
    }

    func (m BaseModel) GetID() uint {
        return m.Id
    }

    type Collection struct {
        Records []Model
    }

    type User struct {
        *BaseModel
        Name string
    }

    func (u User) GetName() string {
        return u.Name
    }

    func main() {
        user := User{&BaseModel{1}, "Jon"}
        uc := &Collection{[]Model{user}}
        u := uc.Records[0].(User)
        fmt.Println(u.GetID())
        fmt.Println(u.GetName())
    }
```